# How to retrieve Apex class (Not sObject) fields in apex dynamically?

Tags: apex, class, describesobject

I have task to test fields from custom class and i need to find all the fields are exist and return expected data.  ex:

```
Class Person{ 
     String Name {get;set;} 
     integer Age {get;set;}
}
//in Test
integer fieldCount =0;
Person p = new Person();
p.Name = 'John';
p.Age = 43;
integer fieldCount = <logic to retrieve field count>
Assert.assertEquals(2,fieldCount);
```

I want to fetch all the class fields for given instance and assert their values, all I am finding is `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` but not finding related to Apex class!. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Apex does not support reflection so there's no built-in mechanism available in the Apex runtime to let you do this.

You would need to use the [tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexclass.htm) to query the ApexClass and its [SymbolTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_symboltable.htm#topic-title). You'll find more information around the tooling API and how to invoke it in the documentation. It is technically possible, if a bit painful, to call the API from Apex. There are even some libraries to help with this, such as [Andrew Fawcett's one](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi).

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
}

Person p = new Person();
p.age = 45;
p.name = 'foo';

String pSerialized = JSON.serialize(p);
Map<String,Object> valsByProperty = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(pSerialized);
System.assertEquals(2,valsByProperty.size());
System.assertEquals(45, (Integer) valsByProperty.get('age');
```

When you serialize, you can exclude null values in the second arg

Reference: [JSON support in Apex doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm?search_text=JSON%20class)